# Is there a Javascript i18n option for 'en-US' without a comma for 4-digit numbers?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I can format a Javascript number by calling `x.toLocaleString()`:

```
// in my US-located browser

>> 100.toLocaleString() 
100

>> 1000.toLocaleString()
1,000

>> 10000.toLocaleString()
10,000
```

But in my application the '1,000' is distracting and I would prefer to keep it just '1000' (which is very common in US English). Obviously I can write my own function to do that, but is there a built-in option that would work?

Comment: then why are you converting it at all?

Comment: Because it's not always a 4-digit number. For larger ones I do need the comma. The order of magnitude is unknown at compile time but is usually 3-5 digits.

Comment: You don't specify that, but it's odd to deviate from the norm in this way. While writing `1000` might be common (is it?), it would be odd to write `1000 to 10,000` in a sentence. (and writing a custom option defeats the purpose of locales as the point is to present information in a consistent format)